# Mongo command from unix shell with different database

Tags: bash, mongodb, shell

I can connect to a mongo server using this command:

> mongo host:port/admin --username=user --password=pass

and I get a mongo shell where I can execute any type of mongo commands after
I switch to the dev db (use dev).

I would like to execute a mongo command from the unix shell / command line
on the dev database, but I have access only to admin.

How can I do that? How can I specify the db I would like to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to execute just a single command, you could do it with:

```
mongo server:22021/my_dbname --eval "printjson(db.serverStatus())"
```

If you wish to execute multiple commands say residing in a file called command.js, you could do something like:

```
mongo server:22021/my_dbname --quiet commands.js
```

If you want pure shell script (SQL) style, then you could do something like:

```
function testMongoScript {
    mongo server:22021/my_dbname <<EOF
       use mydb
       db.leads.findOne()
       db.leads.find().count()
    EOF
}
```

For further details, you could refer [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/) as well.

Comment: Well, the problem is that if i use my_dbname instead of admin, then i get access error, so i need to use the admin credentials, but switch to my_dbname .

Comment: Huh, i didn' t recognize the second part of your comment. mongo host:port/admin --username=user --password=pass << EOF use dev\ndb.collection.find()\nEOF works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use output redirection to run whatever command you need:

```
mongo localhost:27017 <<< $'rs.slaveOk()\nshow dbs'
```

or

```
echo $'rs.slaveOk()\nshow dbs' | mongo localhost:27017
```

just remember the `\n`  between commands.

Answer (score 0):

Use `--authenticationDatabase` to authenticate to the database where your user exists even though you are connecting to a different database:

```
mongo localhost:27017/dev -u user -p **** --authenticationDatabase admin
```

Naturally, you won't be able to do anything in the `dev` database your user doesn't have permissions to do.

Comment: My user has permission to the dev db, just i always need to switch to it with ``use dev'' . This --authenticationDatabase would be a very good option for my problem, however i' ve here mongo 2.0.4 version which seems not to support it... .